# MatAutocompleteModule in a formgroup

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9, formgroups

I have a big form that users can fill in. I wanted a field that would autocomplete your text, and my eye fell on the [Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) component by Angular Material. In the examples, you can see them using the `[formControl]` option in the element. Since my [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) is in a [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup), I had to use the `formGroupName` option for my element in place of the `[formControl]` option. As far as I can tell, this should be fine. However, I run into one issue. Here is my element:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Choose" aria-label="study" matInput formControlName="study" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And this is my controller:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.filteredOptions = this.profileForm.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
}

private _filter(value): string[] {
  console.log(value)
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

  return this.studylist.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
```

As you can see, I've put in a log method. When I log the `value` parameter, it comes up as the value of the entire `profileForm`, as an `object` (it looks like `{value: "", value2: ""}`). I had hoped that all the element would pass through would be the value inside it, but that is not the case. Because of this, the filter doesn't work.

I've tried changing `value.toLowerCase()` to `value.study.toLowerCase()` which just breaks things further and adding `[formControl]` in my element like they show on the documentation, but with `profileForm['study']`, which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to use `.get`

```
this.filteredOptions = this.profileForm.get('study').valueChanges
```

how you bind the control to the input doesn't matter.